# Angular, limitTo and track by $index

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to limit an object coming in by filtering (because there will be an option to show all eventually), however I am running into issues when trying to limitTo and track by index. Here is the code :

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in filter.values track by $index | limitTo:filterLimit" class="cengage-builder-result-filter-value" value="item" update-filter="updateFilter">
```

In the controller:

```
  $scope.filterLimit = 5;
```

It's saying I have dupes in the angular error so I'm thinking the track by $index isn't working here. Can't seem to find a proper way to do this, could use some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Filters, like `limitTo`, `orderBy`, etc... must come before `track by`, since they apply to the array source, rather than to the `track by` expression.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in filter.values | limitTo:filterLimit track by $index">
```

Answer (score 9):

Try this
Use `limitTo`
before `track by`

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in filter.values | limitTo:filterLimit track by $index" class="cengage-builder-result-filter-value" value="item" update-filter="updateFilter">
```

Comment: This makes sense, but for some reason nothing at all is showing up when i do this, no errors either