# How to limit iterations in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-limitto

I want to limit iterations in `ng-repeat` between range. Now I have tried adding filter for range, but as my requirement it is bit lacking. Here is my html.

```
<ul ng-repeat="pitem in ParentArray">
    <h4>{{pitem}}</h4>
    <li ng-repeat="citem in ChildArray|filter:{pcategory:pitem}">{{citem}}</li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, `ChildArray` is filtered based on `pcategory` in `ChildArray`. Now I want to limit `ChildArray` to first 8 iterations. Well after 8 items, we have a button `More Items`. What is the issue is if we limit the ChildArray, `<h4>{{pitem...` would be there. I want to hide it too.

For example, here are three parent items say p1, p2, p3 and in p1 having 4 child items and p2 and p3 having 6 an 10 child items. So limiting ChildArray to 8 then 4 items of p1, 4 items of p2 would be shown. I will show p3 on clicking `More Items` button based on the solution.

**EDIT**

p1, p2 and p3 having child items as below as mentioned above.

```
p1 - c1 to c4
p2 - c1 to c6
p3 - c1 to c10
```

Using `limitTo:8` would show below result

```
<li ng-repeat="citem in ChildArray|limitTo:8|filter:{pcategory:pitem}">{{citem}}</li>

p1 - c1 c2 c3 c4
p2 - c1 c2 c3 c4 
p3
```

Where the required output is

```
p1 - c1 c2 c3 c4
p2 - c1 c2 c3 c4
```

You can see p3 isn't there. Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/66f3bk7a/)

Comment: tried `limitTo: 8`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular, limitTo and track by $index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30201046/angular-limitto-and-track-by-index)

Comment: I don't know why people have voted to close without reading full question. Question is not just to limit ng-repeat. I want to limit parent repeater based on number of iterations of child repeater. Please take a look at example.

Comment: just added childArray length checking to h1 tag if you want to hide pItem too. <h4 ng-if="ChildArray.length > 8">{{pitem}}</h4>

Comment: I think your question is not clear enough to understand properly. Create a plunker that will be great .

Comment: I have updated the question and added jsfiddle link.

Comment: @Viplock : I have added jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As 'digit' said in comment, I added this code.

```
<ul ng-repeat="pitem in ParentArray" ng-if="(child|limitTo:8|filter:{parent:pitem}).length>0">
    <h4>{{pitem}}</h4>
    <li ng-repeat="citem in ChildArray|filter:{pcategory:pitem}">{{citem}}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul ng-repeat="pitem in ParentArray">
    <h4>{{pitem}}</h4>
    <li ng-repeat="citem in ChildArray|filter:{pcategory:pitem} | limitTo: 8">{{citem}}</li>
</ul>
```

angular has a `limitTo` filter for limiting the `ng-repeat`. if you also need to apply the `filter` you can add it in front of `limitTo`

Comment: `limitTo :8` would not hide {{pitem}}